# Slick-Slider отображает слайды некорректно

Tags: html, jquery, css, slick.js

Слайдер сам дает слайдам по 47px, если меняешь вручную костыли.

С чем может быть связана данная проблема?
Корректно отображается только 1 слайд.

CSS:

```
div.portfolioslider {
  margin: 150px 15px 0 15px;
  div.slider {
    width: 100%;
    display: inline;
    div.slide {
      background: #fff;
      box-shadow: 0px 14px 18px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.14);
      border-radius: 15px;
      padding: 0;
      margin: 15px 5% 0 0;
      &:hover img {
        transition: .25s;
        -webkit-filter: grayscale(0%);
      }
      p {
        text-align: center;
        vertical-align: bottom;
        padding: 10px 0;
        font-family: Circe, sans-serif;
        font-weight: 600;
      }
      img {
        width: 100%;
        border-radius: 15px 15px 0 0;
        -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%);
        transition: .25s;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="portfolioslider">
                    <h1>Последние работы</h1>
                    <div class="slider">
                        <div class="slide text-center">
                            <img src="img/slider/1.png" alt="">
                            <p>Всероссийская акция по правилам дорожного движения</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="slide text-center">
                            <img src="img/slider/2.png" alt="">
                            <p>Торговая компания "100Тонн" Строительные материалы.</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="slide text-center">
                            <img src="img/slider/3.png" alt="">
                            <p>Всероссийская акция..</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="slide text-center">
                            <img src="img/slider/4.png" alt="">
                            <p>Всероссийская акция..</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="slide text-center">
                            <img src="img/slider/4.png" alt="">
                            <p>Всероссийская акция..</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="slide text-center">
                            <img src="img/slider/4.png" alt="">
                            <p>Всероссийская акция..</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

JS:

```
<script>
    $('.slider').slick({
        slidesToShow: 4,
        slidesToScroll: 1,
        autoplay: true,
        autoplaySpeed: 2000,
    });
</script>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Задавал col-lg-3, безрезультатно.

Comment: вам как нужно то вообще?

Comment: `margin` между слайдами в процентах замените на `px` и `display: inline` для слайдера уберите.